# Cómo cambiar el tamaño a un submenú que usé con Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

estoy usando Bootstrap v4.6. Cómo puedo hacer para que mi submenu desplegable (está en un div) quede del mismo ancho que su div padre. [Así](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QW_W-7TIByrD0GSGoLTNAELDiz02uyuE/view?usp=sharing) es como queda y [así](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X6-NgRAdrPUpnw99KF06r2C4iltzMlLz/view?usp=sharing) es como necesito que quede. Intenté haciendo:

```
#dropMenuSm {
    width: 100vw;
  }
```

pero esto me coge el ancho del viewport y yo necesito que me quede con el ancho del div padre. Les agradezco su ayuda.

Full código:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light d-flex px-0 bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand bg-dark text-white pl-2 mr-auto p-2" href="/"><img src="" alt=""/><span class="px-3">Something</span></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <div class="ml-auto">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown align-self-center position-relative px-lg-3 d-none d-lg-block" id="appsDropdown">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">APPS<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown align-self-center text-center position-relative d-lg-none d-xl-none" style="cursor: pointer;">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropMobile" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">APPS<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu text-center border-0 bg-primary" id="dropMenuSm" aria-labelledby="navbarDropMobile">
            <a class="dropdown-item-text text-decoration-none text-dark display-4 font-weight-light itemAppsMobile" href="/#">APP1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item-text text-decoration-none text-dark display-4 font-weight-light itemAppsMobile" href="/#">View All</a>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item align-self-center px-lg-3">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/">BLOG</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link btn btn-success text-white m-2 my-2 px-lg-3" href="/#">TRY</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: acceso denegado, acceso denegado... por favor agrega tu código completo y luego explica el problema con el código tuyo.

Comment: Además para obtener el tamaño del ancho del contenedor padre, debes usar porcentaje... 100%

Comment: He agregado tú código a fragmento para poder visualizar el resultado y entender un poco mejor lo que deseas hacer.

Comment: En tu elemento `<li>` del dropdown, sólo elimina la clase `.align-self-center`. Eso debería funcionar. Revisa: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#align-self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución adecuada es como lo sugiere [@jheyman-mejia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/83304/jheyman-mejia) , quitar la clase align-self-center en `<li class="nav-item dropdown text-center position-relative d-lg-none d-xl-none" style="cursor: pointer;">`

Por favor verifica si este es el resultado deseado:

```html
<style>

.align-self-center {
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
}

li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: center;
}

</style>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light d-flex px-0 bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand bg-dark text-white pl-2 mr-auto p-2" href="/"><img src="" alt=""/><span class="px-3">Something</span></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <div class="ml-auto">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown position-relative px-lg-3 d-none d-lg-block" id="appsDropdown">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">APPS<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown text-center position-relative d-lg-none d-xl-none" style="cursor: pointer;">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropMobile" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">APPS<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu text-center border-0 bg-primary" id="dropMenuSm" aria-labelledby="navbarDropMobile">
            <a style="widt:100%" class="dropdown-item-text text-decoration-none text-dark display-4 font-weight-light itemAppsMobile" href="/#">asda sd APP1</a>            <hr>
            <a class="dropdown-item-text text-decoration-none text-dark display-4 font-weight-light itemAppsMobile" href="/#">View asd asd  All</a>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item align-self-center px-lg-3">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/">BLOG</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link btn btn-success text-white m-2 my-2 px-lg-3" href="/#">TRY</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No es buena idea reemplazar las clases del framework, mejor de paso [quítalas y ya](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/452083/c%c3%b3mo-cambiar-el-tama%c3%b1o-a-un-submen%c3%ba-que-us%c3%a9-con-bootstrap#comment805371_452083)

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo.

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta de acuerdo a tu sugerencia, muchas gracias @JheymanMejia

Comment: Hola @elierickdevelopment revisaré tu aporte y te comento. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma que encontré hubiese sido hasta el viewport que se hubiese necesitado pero creo que me quedaré con la solución dada por @elierickdevelopment:

```
.nav-item.dropdown {
    width: 100%;
  }
```